# Multi-color diagonal gradient in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, gradient

I am trying to fill a rectangle with a multi-color diagonal gradient in winforms that looks like the following example: [diagonal gradient](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/Thisrectangleispaintedwithadiagonallineargradient.htm)
I know this is a WPF example, but is it possible to get similar results in winforms?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a little example for you

```
void MainFormPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  LinearGradientBrush br = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle, Color.Black, Color.Black, 0 , false);
  ColorBlend cb = new ColorBlend();
  cb.Positions = new[] {0, 1/6f, 2/6f, 3/6f, 4/6f, 5/6f, 1};
  cb.Colors = new[] {Color.Red, Color.Orange, Color.Yellow, Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.Indigo, Color.Violet};
  br.InterpolationColors= cb;
  // rotate
  br.RotateTransform(45);
  // paint
  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, this.ClientRectangle);
}
```

here is the result

[image]

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in winforms with GDI+, using a `LinearGradientBrush`. Here's a code sample: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/gdiplusbrushes.aspx