# Change ComboBox Border Color - Flash when SelectedIndex changed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I just wanted to know if in windows forms I can create a red line around the border of a combobox when its changed? Like just a flash of red and then gone again just to show that it was changed. Catch the user's eye or something. I will provide screens to represent what i would like.

If it is possible, please tell me where I can look it up to gain some information on it.

No border
[image]
Border flash on change
[image]
Border gone again after a second or two
[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to draw border when `SelectedIndex > -1` ?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I want to draw a border if the combo box changes. From index 1 to 5 or from 3 to 9... Anytime the combobox changes, i want to flash a border to indicate it has changed.

Comment: The main idea is using a timer and drawing a border for some times. You can draw the border using different solutions. For example you can draw the border on `ComboBox` or you can draw it on `Parent` of `ComboBox`. In the answer which I posed, I created a `MyComboBox` and added a `FlashHotBorder` which can be called to flash border.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Anytime the combobox changes, I want to flash a border to indicate it has changed.

The main idea is using a timer and drawing a border for some times. You can draw the border using different solutions. For example you can **(1)** draw the border on `ComboBox` or **(2)** you can draw border on `Parent` of `ComboBox`.

In the answer which I posed, I created a `MyComboBox` and added a `FlashHotBorder` method which can be called to flash border. Also I added a `HotBorderColor` property which can be used to set border color.

**Flashing Border of ComboBox**

To draw a border for `ComboBox` you can handle [`WM_Paint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) message of `ComboBox` and draw a border for control. Then to flash the border, you need to use a timer and turn on and turn off border for some times:

[image]

**MyComboBox Code**

I've created a `FlashHotBorder` method which you can call in `SelectedIndexChanged` event. Also if always you want to flash border when selected index changes, you can call it in `OnSelectedIndexChanged`. I prefer to call it in event handler. Here is the implementation:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    int flash = 0;
    private const int WM_PAINT = 0xF;
    private int buttonWidth = SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarArrowWidth;
    public Color HotBorderColor { get; set; }
    private bool DrawBorder { get; set; }
    Timer timer;
    public MyComboBox()
    {
        this.HotBorderColor = Color.Red;
        timer = new Timer() { Interval = 100 };
        timer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT && this.DrawBorder)
            using (var g = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle))
            using (var p = new Pen(this.HotBorderColor))
                g.DrawRectangle(p, 0, 0, this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1);
    }
    public void FlashHotBorder()
    {
        flash = 0;
        timer.Start();
    }
    void timer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (flash < 10)
        {
            flash++;
            this.DrawBorder = !this.DrawBorder;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Stop();
            flash = 0;
            DrawBorder = false;
        }
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) { timer.Dispose(); }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Then it's enough to use this event handler for `SelectedIndexChanged` event of eeach combo which you want to flash:

```
private void myComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var combo = sender as FlatCombo;
    if (combo != null)
        combo.FlashHotBorder();
}
```

Comment: liked the way, the border flashes :)

Comment: @Cleaven Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you for this! It is exactly what I wanted. The perfect answer. Thank you so much :) I will ask if i come across anything when i implement it.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I posted a suggestive answer if you want to see it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create an outline/draw a border outside a *comboBox* or any other *control* using the [`DrawRectangle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx8yykw8(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) method.

The border will be drawn outside the comboBox if the *SelectedIndex* range condition satisfies else it'll revert to it's original state with no outline.

```
bool changed = false;
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (changed)
    {
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red);
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        int diff = 1;
        g.DrawRectangle(p, new Rectangle(comboBox1.Location.X - diff, comboBox1.Location.Y - diff, comboBox1.Width + diff, comboBox1.Height + diff));
    }
}
```

And, I am calling the `Form1_Paint` event on `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the comboBox.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex >= 1 && comboBox1.SelectedIndex <= 9)
    {
        changed = true;
        this.Refresh();
    }
    else
    {
        changed = false;
        this.Refresh();
    }
}
```

**Outline**                                         **Without Outline**

[image: outline]   [image: without outline]

Comment: I just want to know where you calling the Form1_Paint method cause i tried to do this but my comobobox doesn't retrieve a border at all.

Comment: @Cleaven **Right-click** your _Form_ to open up the **Properties** window. Go to the **Events** window and there just call the [Paint](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MbEVS.png) event of the form :)

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with this. It's the shortest and easiest way to do it I think. If you have any recommendation, feel free to post them or comment it. thanx for all the help :).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int tick = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    bool changed = false;        
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (changed == true)
        {
            changed = false;
            this.Refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            if(tick<3)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                timer1.Start();  
            }                          
            changed = true;
            this.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (changed)
        {              
            Graphics g1 = e.Graphics;
            int diff = 1;
            Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(comboBox1.Location.X - diff, comboBox1.Location.Y - diff, comboBox1.Width + diff, comboBox1.Height + diff);
            using (LinearGradientBrush br = new LinearGradientBrush(rect2,Color.Red,Color.Blue,LinearGradientMode.Horizontal))
            {
                ColorBlend color_blend = new ColorBlend();
                color_blend.Colors = new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Orange, Color.Yellow, Color.Lime, Color.Blue, Color.Indigo, Color.DarkViolet};
                color_blend.Positions = new float[] { 0 / 6f, 1 / 6f, 2 / 6f, 3 / 6f, 4 / 6f, 5 / 6f, 6 / 6f };
                br.InterpolationColors = color_blend;
                Pen p = new Pen(br, 10);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, rect2);
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Transparent);
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            int diff = 1;
            g.DrawRectangle(p, new Rectangle(comboBox1.Location.X - diff, comboBox1.Location.Y - diff, comboBox1.Width + diff, comboBox1.Height + diff));
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(tick<3)
        {
            comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
            tick++;
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            tick = 0;
        }

    }     
}
```

Comment: Any idea how i can make the border like rainbow colors?

Comment: *1)* Create a rectangle `var r= comboBox1.bounds`, then to grow or shrink a rectangle use `r.Inflate(2,2)` which performs the job which you are doing using `diff`. *2)* You need to use `FillRectangle` instead of `DrawRectangle`. Also a rotation seems to be good. *3)* Currently the method can be used only for a single `ComboBox`. How many combo boxes do you have which need such feature?

Comment: @RezaAghaei at the moment it is only this combobox but if it changes I can easily create a method and just pass through the name of the combobox as the sender... I think that will work, shouldn't it? the rainbow isn't a need but i thought now that we on this topic, it could be a useful piece of code to keep if we can make it like rainbow colors in ther brush maybe?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8406327/3110834) for rainbow effect. It's a good example and simply can be applied on your code using tips which I mentioned in note No.1.

Comment: About multiple combo box, yes, it can be used also using multiple combo boxes but probably it makes your code messy.Using inheritance or creating an extender component which encapsulates the logic is good for such cases.