# Changing the border color of a Combobox on focus

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, combobox, custom-controls

I have a custom `ComboBox`.

I want to give a custom `BorderColor` to the `ComboBox`, when it is focused.

To do this, I'm using the following code:

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle);
Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);

ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, bounds, BaseConfigurations.StyleColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
```

The thing is, if I use the code inside the `MouseHover` event
when I move the mouse on the `ComboBox` control, I can see that it works.
However, the same code does not work inside the `GotFocus` Event, and I can't figure out why..  any help is appreciated.

Comment: That code just splatters pixels on top of the control, you in general cannot predict when they are going to be overdrawn when the ComboBox repaints itself.  Just drag the window off the screen and back to see another basic failure mode.  It gets much worse from there, the textbox portion paints without using the paint event.  A crime that mattered 30 years ago.  You cannot make this reliable as-is, the container could draw a rectangle around it.

Comment: Well, I've noticed (someone made me) that I've posted here the (very similar) answer to a question asked in another site (which got yours :). If, by chance, you have already seen this and the code appeared somewhat (!) different from the graphics presentation, it's now the right code. (Sorry).

Comment: You can use the solution which is shared here: [Change ComboBox Border Color - Flash when SelectedIndex changed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39053998/3110834).

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple Class that inherits from `ComboBox` and exposes two properties that allows to set the Active and Inactive border of the Control.

The painting is done using the Parent Form `Paint()` event, invalidating only the area around the selected control.

The Parent `Paint()` event is subscribed in the custom ComboBox `OnHandleCreated()` event, along with the control's `Enter()`, `Leave()` and `Move()` events.
Subscribing the `Move()` event is required to paint a transparent border, otherwise the border will remain painted on the Parent client area while dragging the control at Design time.

I've also added `DropDownBackColor()` and `DropDownForeColor()` properties, which become active if the custom ComboBox `DrawMode` is set to `OwnerDrawVariable` (as usual).

This is how it looks like:

[image]

```
public class CustomCombo : ComboBox
{
    private Color ActionBorderColor = Color.Empty;
    public CustomCombo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Color BorderActive { get; set; }
    public Color BorderInactive { get; set; }
    public Color DropDownBackColor { get; set; }
    public Color DropDownForeColor { get; set; }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
        this.BorderActive = Color.OrangeRed;
        this.BorderInactive = Color.Transparent;
        this.DropDownBackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Window);
        this.DropDownForeColor = this.ForeColor;
        this.HandleCreated += new EventHandler(this.OnControlHandle);
    }

    protected void OnControlHandle(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Form parent = this.FindForm();
        parent.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.ParentPaint);
        this.Enter += (s, ev) => { this.InvalidateParent(BorderActive); };
        this.Leave += (s, ev) => { this.InvalidateParent(BorderInactive); };
        this.Move += (s, ev) => { this.InvalidateParent(Color.Transparent); };
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    }

    private void InvalidateParent(Color bordercolor)
    {
        ActionBorderColor = bordercolor;
        Rectangle rect = this.Bounds;
        rect.Inflate(2, 2);
        this.FindForm().Invalidate(rect);
    }

    protected void ParentPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rect = this.Bounds;
        rect.Inflate(1, 1);
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(ActionBorderColor, 1))
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SolidBrush bkBrush = new SolidBrush(this.DropDownBackColor))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(bkBrush, e.Bounds);
        using (SolidBrush foreBbrush = new SolidBrush(this.DropDownForeColor))
            e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Items[e.Index].ToString(),
                                  this.Font, foreBbrush, new PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
}
```