# Change ComboBox border outline color

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am trying to manage the color of the ComboBox. While it is possible to change the background color, I cannot find a property for the border outline.

Just drawing a square as border wont do in a dark theme because of the arrow. This leads me to the conclusion that this border might be an actual image file.

Is it possible to replace this?

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I have implemented the Solution of @AhmedAbdelhameed - It looks a lot better now. However for the flat style, I had to adjust the rectangle like the following:

```
using (var p = new Pen(this.BorderColor, 1))
{
    g.DrawRectangle(p, 0, 0, Width - buttonWidth - 1, Height - 1);
}
```

I also exchanged the 'BorderColor' to match the rest of my UI:

```
public CustomComboBox()
{
    BorderColor = Color.Gray;
}
```

This is the result so far:
[image]
[image]

What I would like to be able to do now is to change the actual drop down button (maybe with an overlay png) *only in dark theme*

**UPDATE:**
I have been able to add a pricturebox to the custom Control with the following code:

```
using (var g = Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle))
{
    using (var p = new Pen(this.BorderColor, 1))
    {
        g.DrawRectangle(p, 0, 0, Width - buttonWidth - 1, Height - 1);
    }
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.Theme == "Dark")
    {
        g.DrawImageUnscaled(Properties.Resources.dropdown, new Point(Width - buttonWidth - 1));
    }
}
```

it looks awesome!
more or less by coincidence which I do not understand, the dark dropdown button even disappears, when I change the theme in the theme combobox.

**Before - After Comparisation:**
[image] 
[image]

Comment: There are a property named `BackColor`. For more information, please [read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.backcolor)

Comment: @dbvega That's not the issue.

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34877280/4934172), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49302435/4934172) too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34886006/4934172), I was able to come up with the following:

First, add the following into your form to avoid flickering:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams handleParam = base.CreateParams;
        handleParam.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;      // WS_EX_COMPOSITED
        return handleParam;
    }
}
```

Now, add the following class to your project:

```
public class CustomComboBox : ComboBox
{
    private const int WM_PAINT = 0xF;
    private int buttonWidth = SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarArrowWidth;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT)
        {
            using (var g = Graphics.FromHwnd(Handle))
            {
                // Uncomment this if you don't want the "highlight border".
                /*
                using (var p = new Pen(this.BorderColor, 1))
                {
                    g.DrawRectangle(p, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);
                }*/
                using (var p = new Pen(this.BorderColor, 2))
                {
                    g.DrawRectangle(p, 2, 2, Width - buttonWidth - 4, Height - 4);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public CustomComboBox()
    {
        BorderColor = Color.DimGray;
    }

    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "DimGray")]
    public Color BorderColor { get; set; }
}
```

Rebuild the project, replace the ComboBox controls with the new `CustomComboBox`, set the `BorderColor` property to a color of your choice, and you're good to go.

**Result:**

[image: ComboBox_BorderColor]

**Update:**

Using the following values seems to give a better result *(specially when clicking the dropdown button)*, but you'll still probably need to draw the first rectangle (the one commented above) to avoid showing the "highlight border" around the button only:

```
using (var p = new Pen(this.BorderColor, 3))
{
    g.DrawRectangle(p, 1, 1, Width - buttonWidth - 3, Height - 3);
}
```

Comment: I think I have to thank you for linking that ugly a?? of an answer I posted a while ago. I've updated it (for what is possible, at least it doesn't leak anymore). I've made a class out of that Reza Aghaei's answer myself. [This is a PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/CycVmSjK) I had posted (for another site) with the relevant parts. I think there's one thing that needs to be added (when implementing this): `SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true)` in the constructor. IIRC, it helps.

Comment: @Jimi Actually, `SetStyle` is what I went with at first but it doesn't seem to get rid of the flicker in this particular case (for some reason!). That's why I replaced it with overriding the `CreateParams` property at the form level, which works for me every time.

Comment: Yes, sure. I meant, it helps in the form designer, to get the drawing right when resizing the controls (depending on the actual implementation). The flickering is another story; I know that setting `CreateParams` that way is a good workaround in this cases.

Comment: Hello Ahmed, thank you for your answer which will already help a lot. Do you think there is also the possibility to get this sqare with a triangle on the right hand side of the Combobox dark? Maybe by overlaying a png? I will implement your solution and update my question then.

Comment: @julian bechtold  If you modify the Control style, with `SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |                      ControlStyles.UserPaint, true)`, then the `Paint` event will be raised and you can paint anything in the Button area. It'ld take some more work, though. The `WndProc` WM_PAINT override could me moved to the Paint event. All the control's NC area design falls in your hands.

Comment: @Jimini, I already updated my question ;) I do it a little "easier" but it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

To add a border for the full width of the combobox you have to remove the button width from the drawing. In my case, I simply wanted to change the color of the border so 1 pixel was sufficient.

```
using (var p = new Pen(this.BorderColor, 1))
{
    g.DrawRectangle(p, 0, 0, Width - 1, Height - 1);
}
```

That meant that the custom combobox behaved exactly like the generic one e.g on hover etc