# draw gradient color for form border

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to ask how do i add another color to the gradient color. iam currently using this code

```
  private void add3_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush brush = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle, Color.LightPink, Color.Gold, System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal);           
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new System.Drawing.Pen(brush,10), this.ClientRectangle);
        brush.Dispose();
    }
```

the result was like this

[image]

**for the purple was panel control using dock bottom, please ignore it !**.
what iam asking is as you can see iam using gradient color `light pink` and `gold`. but i want to add another color, e.g add another color green and add another color red (any slot for color) but the code i use only accessible for `two` color

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8406327/5045688

Comment: thanks for the reference !